# Conditionally enable x-ray for API Gateway and Lambda in serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-xray

I am trying to enable x-ray only when I needed to save some bucks. The following `serverless.yml` loads the environment variables from the `.env` file. However, it seems like serverless only allows `true`, `Active` and `PassThrough`. Any possible way to bypass this? Thanks.

```yaml
# serverless.yml

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  logs:
    restApi: ${env:ENABLE_X_RAY, false}
  tracing:
    apiGateway: ${env:ENABLE_X_RAY, false}
    lambda: ${env:ENABLE_X_RAY, false}

plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
```

```yaml
# .env

ENABLE_X_RAY=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the entry point of your service is API Gateway you can configure Sampling Rules and limits on the AWS X-Ray console or using API to control the number of requests that are sampled by X-Ray.

See this article for an introduction to sampling in X-Ray:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/apigateway-xray/

Let me know if you have further questions regarding this.

**Update**

Sampling rules may be specified only in X-Ray.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html
This allows you to limit the number of traces no matter how many API Gateway or  EC2 instances you have for handling your requests.

Small caveat: As of today, this mode of sampling is supported only if the entry point is API Gateway or if you have the >2.0 version of X-Ray daemon running on your instances (EC2 or otherwise). If the entry point is lambda this sampling effect is not supported today but will be supported soon.

In your case it seems you are using API Gateway as your entry point, so you can definitely [configure sampling rules in X-Ray console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html) and have that take effect globally across all your API Gateway endpoints.

You can also configure different sampling rules for different URLs like /auth is sampled at 5 TPS and /products is configured for 1 TPS with different reservoirs based on your usecase.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit for the info. Had a quick lock on both API Gateway and API Gateway V2's template reference, it seems like currently the x-ray and sampling rules are not supported in CloudFormation and assume that I will have to create a custom resource with Lambda to achieve this? Preferably to look for an IaC solution if possible.

Comment: Sampling Rules are specified in X-Ray

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify that sampling rules need to be configured in X-Ray console and they will have a global effect to all your API Gateway handlers. No need to configure anything in your template.